# PHP string to float strange

Tags: php, string

I don't understand the result ?! 29.85-3.5527136788005E-15
PHP bug ? Same result with floatval or cast
can you help me ? The simple example code  here :

```
<?php 
$new = array('29.85');
$two = array('6.95','9.95','12.95');
$montantTotal = 0 ;
foreach ($two as $lignes) {
    $montantTotal += floatval($lignes);
    }
echo $montantTotal ;
$result = $montantTotal - floatval($new[0]);
echo $result;
```

Comment: [Read, learn and understand](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) This is common to all languages that use IEEE-754

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The E means `exponential` and you're getting a very small number because of how borked floating point math is. To correct the issue, you must use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to get a correct display.

Comment: If you had a person write down the result of `1/3` on a piece of paper they'd probably write something like `0.3333333` but because the paper doesn't fit all the digits, when they then do a `0.333333 * 3` they don't get 1 as they should but something like `0.9999999`. Is maths broken? No, we just don't have enough paper.

Comment: Computers can't store the exact values of many float numbers like the result of (1/3). that is why you should keep a rounding function and float comparison function as your companions when you are doing float arithmetic stuff

Comment: see this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833596/5407848](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833596/5407848)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

**Syntax**

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

**Example**

```
    $new = array('29.85');
    $two = array('6.95','9.95','12.95');
    $montantTotal = 0 ;
    foreach ($two as $lignes) {
        $montantTotal += (float)$lignes;
        }
   // echo $montantTotal ; echo "<br>";
    $result = number_format($montantTotal,8,".","") - number_format((float)$new[0],8,".","");
    echo $result;
```

**Output**

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Result is very small. It use scientific notation.

```
 $montantTotal =  29.85
 $result = -3.5527136788005E-15
```